# Cannot find class error, no idea what's wrong

Tags: java, processing

Today i have stumbled upon the most fatal error of all errors. Processing doesn't see my class... I have no clue why it doesn't, since i'm pretty new at this.

This is my main class:

```
Player thePlayer = new Player();
Guard theGuard = new Guard();
SpeedPWRUP speedPowerUp = new SpeedPWRUP();
Keyboard theKeyboard = new Keyboard();

void setup() {
  size(1000, 500);
  theGuard.init();
  thePlayer.init();
  speedPowerUp.init();
}

void updateGame() {
  theGuard.update();
  thePlayer.update();
  speedPowerUp.update();
}

void drawGame() {
  thePlayer.draw();
  theGuard.draw();
  speedPowerUp.draw();
  fill(color(0, 0, 0));
  text(("Score:"), 10, 20);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  fill (0, 0, 0);
  rect(-10, 401, 1100, 100);
  noFill();

  updateGame();
  drawGame();
  Keyboard();
}
```

And this is my player class:

```
  class Player {

  public float playerX, playerY;
  float vx, vy;
  int fillColor;
  float diameterPlayer;
  float jumpTime;
  float jumpHeight;
  boolean isJumping;
  float collisionGuard;
  boolean speedUpActive;
  boolean facingRight;

void init() {
  diameterPlayer = 40;
  fillColor = color(0, 0, 0);
  jumpTime = 200;
  jumpHeight = 100;
  isJumping = false;
  collisionGuard = 80;
  speedUpActive = false;
  facingRight = false;

  playerX = 100;
  playerY = 400-diameterPlayer;

  vx = 0;
  vy = 0;
}

void update() {

  if(theKeyboard.holdingUp == true && isOnGround == true) {
    vx = 5;
    isOnGround = false;
  }

  if(theKeyboard.holdingDown == true) {
    diameterPlayer = 40;
  }

  if(theKeyboard.holdingLeft == true) {
    vx = -2;
  }

  if(theKeyboard.holdingRight == true) {
    vx = 2;
  }

  if (playerY < (400-diameterPlayer/2)) {
  vy = vy + 2.5;
  }

  if (playerY < (80-diameterPlayer/2)) {
  vy = 2.5;
  }

  if (playerX < (0+diameterPlayer/2)) {
  vx = 0.1;
  }

  if(vx>0) {
    facingRight = true;
  } else if(vx<0) { facingRight = false;
  } else facingRight = false;

  playerX += vx;
  playerY += vy;

}

void draw() {
  fill(fillColor);
  ellipse(playerX, playerY, diameterPlayer, diameterPlayer);
  noFill();
}
}
```

The error occurs in the first line of my main class ("Player thePlayer = new Player();"), the error says "Cannot find class or type "Player"". Someone please help me :( Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you imported your `Player` class?!

Comment: In Processing IDE the class Player has been recognised. The error is about the Guard class which is expected with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

If `Player` class is not in same package as of `Main` class. Then you need to import Player class in Main class as below.

```
import XXX.Player;
```

// Your Main class code goes here.

Answer (score 0):

Place your Player class above main class in your code. Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Put your Player class on the same directory with Main class
otherwise import with full package name where Player classes stored.... Or may be there is small or capital difference.....

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported your class Player to the same package as of the Main class?

Make Player public and try again:

> public class Player { ... }

Comment: Tried it, doesn'y work.. The classes are all in the same folder so importing shouldn't be neccesary?

Comment: This may sounds stupid, but have you tried to start eclipse/netbeans or whatever you're using again? I once had a problem that was alike to yours and strangely restarting Netbeans helped.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i thought too at first. So i tried it and it didn't work. So now i'm pretty much stuck, thanks for the help anyways! :D